# Getting error while installing Firebase tools in Linux

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, web, angular-cli

I am working in Angular and want to connect my project to Firebase using the following command

```
ng add @angular/fire
```

but getting the following error.

```
ℹ Using package manager: npm
⚠ Package has unmet peer dependencies. Adding the package may not succeed.

The package @angular/fire@7.4.1 will be installed and executed.
Would you like to proceed? Yes
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: sell-well@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@16.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"^16.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^12.0.0 || ^13.0.0 || ^14.0.0" from @angular/fire@7.4.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/fire
npm ERR!   @angular/fire@"7.4.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /home/user/.npm/_logs/2023-05-12T13_20_07_691Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/.npm/_logs/2023-05-12T13_20_07_691Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code.  Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's [easy to read, copy, and search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/807126).  You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.